# How can I use variable to select graphql object nested fields?

Tags: graphql

I have a graphql schema:

```
type User {
  name: Name
}
type Name {
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
}
query {
  user(id: ID!): User
}
```

when I query this endpoint, I am using:

```
gql`
  query user(id: "xx"){
    name {
      firstName
    }
  }

`
```

it works fine until I'd like to use variable to choose the select fields. How can I use variable to replace the select part? I'd like to store below in a variable and pass it to `gpl` to select.

```
name {
      firstName
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At this time, there is no syntax for that:

- **variables are for values only** in graphql,
- selection must be explicit.

You can use **query string** [or AST] **manipulations** (on client using FE language) during request preparation.